# Error while installing libpulse-dev package in ubuntu

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-16.04, apt

When i try to install libpulse-dev i am getting error as 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpulse-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Please help me

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpulse-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

==

Answer (score 0):

You should install libglib2.0-dev

Answer (score 0):

If can't install libpulse-dev,
try:

```
locate libpulse-mainloop-glib.so
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -sf libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0.0.5 libpulse-mainloop-glib.so
locate libpulse.so
sudo ln -sf libpulse.so.0 libpulse.so
```

Answer (score 0):

This will install the required package `sudo apt-get install libpulse-mainloop-glib0`